# How do spaceships' Armor and Toughness work?

Tags: savage-worlds, vehicles

I'm new to *Savage Worlds*, and in my preparation phase of creating a Sci-Fi campaign. I'm borrowing from the last parsec, and the original sci-fi companion to make a homebrew of sorts.

I'm confused about how spaceships' Armor and Toughness work. If they work the way I think, the light lasers are useless.

Take, for example, a medium spaceship. Toughness 25, Armor 6.

Light lasers do 2d10 damage and AP at 5. Which means that unless one of the dice ace, there's no way the light lasers can get past a TN of 26.

Here's my math:

- Toughness 25 + 6 Armor = TN of 31
- AP of 5 ignores 5 of the 6 armor points,
  for 26 as the TN

2d10 with no aces is 18. At least 1 would need to ace to pass 26.

Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Thank you @Ben! Even small ships have 20 toughness and 5 armor, so the light lasers are not much use in space I guess. :) They are only useful for land vehicles.

Comment: Another relevant source of information is the [Pinnacle forums](https://www.pegforum.com/), which have an official answers section.

Comment: @ValhallaGH, thanks for the forums link! I missed that when I was on their site. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Armor is Included in Toughness

So, a Toughness 25 (6) vehicle has a **total** Toughness 25, but 6 of it comes from armor. AP subtracts from the armor of the target, ignoring some of the armor when determining Wounds.

In the case of a Light Laser, damage is 2d10 (+1d6 with a raise on the Shooting result) against [25 - 5 = 20] Toughness 20 (1). Not great odds of effective damage, but significantly better than against Toughness 26.

---

Linked can improve the effectiveness of Light weapons. 

Dual-linked weapons function like a single weapon - one attack roll and one damage roll - but get +1 to Shooting and +2 to the final damage.

Quad-linked weapons function like a single weapon - one attack roll and one damage roll - but get +2 to Shooting and +4 to the final damage.

*Example:* Dual-Linked Light Lasers have +1 to Shooting and deal 2d10+2 damage, but you only make one Shooting attack and one damage roll to fire both weapons simultaneously. 
 Quad-Linked would work the same, but the bonuses are +2 and +4.

Comment: Just to add to this, perhaps you could talk about Linked weaponry (a lot of ship weapons - particularly light weapons are often linked, or quad-linked)

Comment: @Ben Good idea. Added to answer.

Comment: That makes much more sense! **Thank you!**

Upgrading the ship to linked medium lasers. :) With the +2 damage and the AP ignoring the 6 points from armor, there's a decent chance for hits. :)